# Strange characters in string with c# sockets

Tags: c#, string, sockets, character-encoding

We are working on an RTS game using XNA, and I've been tasked with the networking (well, we kind of finished the game, and I recently picked it back up). To cut to the chase, I have had a ton of issues with sockets, missing packets mostly for a lot of different reasons, but I think I've solved most of them. (We're using TCP even ..)

To try to solve issues, I've created a network tester, which will send packets to the server, which will send them back, after which I can see if there were dropped packets etc.

One of my tests is a 'deform' test. Basically I grab the random function, generate a number, convert it to an MD5 String, and send it to the server. When I receive it back, I compare it to the strings already sent, and see if there was any corruption (comparison *should* be 100%, as in, all sent strings were found in the received list).

Now, here's a snapshot of the results:

Sent:

```
    [0] "69-AB-DA-CC-1A-66-6A-27-C5-B4-FF-B7-2D-9F-75-06"   string
    [1] "1C-16-68-98-DF-6C-C9-16-54-5A-94-00-CA-57-77-CC"   string
    [2] "B6-24-7E-79-0C-66-14-5B-C0-32-F5-17-06-5D-13-87"   string
    [3] "1E-99-DE-1F-25-30-6E-DF-59-0D-05-2B-43-8F-07-16"   string
    [4] "76-82-30-13-C2-B4-33-7D-32-E2-04-C7-13-3C-F3-AB"   string
    [5] "23-BF-A2-F4-E4-77-78-6B-A5-2C-D2-6B-6F-B3-6F-44"   string
```

Received:

```
    [0] "&\0\069-AB-DA-CC-1A-66-6A-27-C5-B4-FF-B7-2D-9F-75-06"  string
    [1] "&\0\01C-16-68-98-DF-6C-C9-16-54-5A-94-00-CA-57-77-CC"  string
    [2] "B6-24-7E-79-0C-66-14-5B-C0-32-F5-17-06-5D-13-87"   string
    [3] "1E-99-DE-1F-25-30-6E-DF-59-0D-05-2B-43-8F-07-16"   string
    [4] "76-82-30-13-C2-B4-33-7D-32-E2-04-C7-13-3C-F3-AB"   string
    [5] "23-BF-A2-F4-E4-77-78-6B-A5-2C-D2-6B-6F-B3-6F-44"   string
```

I'm getting roughly 50% packets correct. I could post the socket code and such, but I dare say it's rather complex. Still, if it's needed, I'll post it. Is there some socket-related thing I'm missing? I am hoping for a quick fix .. but I doubt there will be any seeing previous problems we had.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Edit: View the github repository here: https://github.com/Wotuu/RTS_XNA_v2/tree/master/SocketLibrary

By request, some code snapshots:
MD5 creation: https://github.com/Wotuu/RTS_XNA_v2/blob/master/PathfindingTest/PathfindingTest/UI/Menus/Multiplayer/TestConnectionMenu.cs :222

String->byte: https://github.com/Wotuu/RTS_XNA_v2/blob/master/SocketLibrary/Packets/Packet.cs :113

byte->String: https://github.com/Wotuu/RTS_XNA_v2/blob/master/SocketLibrary/Packets/PacketUtil.cs

Comment: It would be great to see code which send and receive a data

Comment: or more specifically code that performs string->byte[]->string conversion

Comment: To be honest, even just the *mention* of "string" makes me very suspicious here. (mis-)Treating binary as a string is pretty-much guaranteed to cause corruption...

Comment: using TCP, there should not be any packet loss! can you post the function, that converts your MD5 string to bytes that get send over the socket, and as well the function that converts the received bytes back to the string.

Comment: sll: I think the GitHub repository will show you the code you need. https://github.com/Wotuu/RTS_XNA_v2/tree/master/SocketLibrary
liho1eye: https://github.com/Wotuu/RTS_XNA_v2/blob/master/SocketLibrary/Packets/Packet.cs
Marc Gravell: If you got time, check the above links, I'm not totally sure what you mean, but it seems legit.
esskar: That's my thought exactly, but still it happens! I'll add snippets to my original post.

Comment: Your StringToBytes and BytesToString are **not** equivalent with eachother; BytesToString uses byte <===> code point, which is not the same as UTF8 (although earlier this week I found out that it is the same as Codepage 28591 or something like that)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have replaced the code with code found here: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_320.asp . This would lead me to believe that the byte[] <--> string conversion is going correctly this time 'round (although I can't see what is wrong with my initial conversion). However, I'm getting the exact same results using both functions. Any other idea? (p.s., the obscure construction I have in place in handling received bytes is a result of the endless bugfixing I tried, and haven't bothered to convert to a 'better' system, but this *should* work as it is!)

Answer (score 2):

Please keep in mind that TCP is a streaming protocol.  There is no guarantee that the receiving socket will receive a specific sized packet.  The recipient is responsible for re-assembling the possibly random sized packets it receives into a coherent message.

Comment: This is usually the #1 cause of issues with TCP

Comment: I have, in fact, thought about that. I end all packets with a '|', and split on that character every time I receive bytes. Could it be that TCP also splits in the middle of packets? I don't account for that, which may cause the issue (but would be odd since I've never ever seen half packets in my months of testing). Cheers for the reply anyways.